# с# wfp как сделать тумблер?

Tags: c#, wpf

В wpf не силен, так что написать свой элемент наверное не судьба. Решил наследоваться от кнопки и изменять ее цвет по нажатию. Но вот проблема, цвет изменяется по событию "click", а мне нужно будет по этому событию делать еще и другие действия. Как бы сделать так, что бы у меня было двойное событие. 
т.е. что бы я мог подписаться на событие "click" по моему тумблеру и при этом выполнялась и смена цвета и определенные действия в событии.

Пока не начал писать, велосипед казался не таким страшным))
Может кто посоветует вариант по проще....

Comment: чекбокс - не вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Всего то надо было порыться в компонентах. 
ToggleButton вполне подходит)

Comment: Возможно, имеет смысл (1) добавить код, и (2) поставить галочку вашему ответу.